# Use of undeclared identifier in function

Tags: c

I get "Use of undeclared identifier 'data'" when I compile that code. As you can see the problem is that add_student function can't "see" student array.

What to do so to work properly ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int  age;
    char *sex;
    int  class;
}student;


void add_student(int, char*, int, char*, int);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    student data[5];

    add_student(5, "Mery", 3, "female", 8);
    return 0;
}

void add_student(int sequence, char *name, int age, char *sex, int class) {
    strcpy(data[sequence].name, name);
    data[sequence].age[13];
    strcpy(data[sequence].sex, sex);
    data[sequence].class[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to fix this is by passing `data` as an additional argument to `add_student()`.

There are other errors, such as

1. passing `5` as the value of `sequence` and then using it to index into `data`;
2. the use of `strcpy()` is incorrect as you haven't allocated memory for the `name` and `sex` fields;
3. the expressions `data[sequence].age[13]` and `data[sequence].class[2]` are not valid C.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to allocate memory for name and sex. Here how I did (sorry but didn't found a way to format the code)
 data[sequence].name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);<
    strcpy(data[sequence].name, name);
    data[sequence].age = age;
    data[sequence].sex = malloc(strlen(sex) + 1);
    strcpy(data[sequence].sex, sex);
    data[sequence].class = class;

Comment: @user1074077: No, `malloc()` is fine. There's also `strdup()`. In either case, don't forget to `free()`!

Comment: @user1074077: In this case I'd probably have a `delete_student()` function doing the cleanup, and would call it from `main()`.

Comment: I get the idea. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

`data` is in the scope of `main()`, and you're trying to use it in the scope of `add_student()`. You have two options:

1. Put `data` in global scope, i.e. put its declaration outside of any functions.
2. Pass `data` into `add_student()` as a parameter.

I generally prefer the latter, but there's use cases for both. Doing the first option will remove the need to pass along the length of the array, which you'd have to do if you passed it in as a parameter.